# How can I commit my added files in git?

Tags: git, commit

I added some files to my repository via `git add`.
Now I want to commit them

```
git commit -m „I did something“
```

But it is just not working. I do not know what to do. I always get the message

> error: pathspec 'did' did not match any file(s) known to git.
>
> error: pathspec 'something“' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: The troublemakers are the "smart" quotes you are using. Command line and programming use only straight quotes (`"`).

Comment: Oh wow. Did not know this

Comment: @jarla are you Spanish?

Comment: @evolutionxbox why?

Comment: @Jarla ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ just curious really.

Comment: @ no not spanish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The troublemakers are the "smart" quotes you are using. Command line and programming use only straight quotes (`"`).

The quotes you are using do not have any special meaning, the shell parses `„I`, `did` and `something“` as three words and passes them as command line arguments to `git`.

Git interprets `„I` as the argument of `-m` (the commit message) and the other two words as the names of [the files to commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit). It displays the error messages you posted because it cannot find any file with those names.

The solution is to always use either straight quotes (`"`) or apostrophes (`'`) in the command line (they have different meaning but in this context they are equivalent). If the commit message contains quotes you can wrap the message in apostrophes and the other way around.

```
git commit -m "I did something"
```

or:

```
git commit -m 'I did something'
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you get this low quote mark ?

```
git commit -m „I did something“
              ^
```

In you run this as is in a shell (which is expecting traditional " marks at both sides), this won't be view as an one-block string. Git will therefore assume that's three different parameters, the two last ones being filenames.

Try

```
git commit -m "I did something"
```

… instead, if you need to cut and paste it.